# Trying to disable the whole f.select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to disable a dropdown field in my form, but with the option disable: true the field is still clickable, thanks for the help!

***f.select:***

```
<%= f.select(:point_constraint_id, @point_constraints.collect {|u| [u.name, u.id]}, :prompt => 'Select', label: t('point.operational_limitions')  + ' *', label_class: "light-text", disabled: true, required: true )%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby reads hash like parameters in the parameter list as one hash when they are at the end of the parameter list. Therefore all options are passed to the `options` hash. But the signature of the [`select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) method looks like this:

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

Therefore you need to separate the `options` from the `html_options` to help Ruby to understand that `disable: true` is actually a `html_option`:

```
<%= f.select(
      :point_constraint_id, 
      @point_constraints.collect { |u| [u.name, u.id] }, 
      { 
        prompt: 'Select', 
        label: "#{t('point.operational_limitions')}*", 
        label_class: "light-text", 
        required: true
      }, 
      { 
        disabled: true 
      } 
    ) %>
```

Note the last `{...}` around the `disabled: true` is actually not needed. I added it to make it clearer that you need to pass two hashes to that method. One with the options for the select, another for pure the HTML options.

Comment: solved my problem perfectly and even gave an excellent explanation, thank you very much, really !!